# Group by not ordering by date correctly

Tags: mysql

I have a query that lists theme parks by order of newest news story. The query is below.

```
$sql2 = 'SELECT tpf_news.park_id, name
FROM tpf_news
INNER JOIN tpf_parks ON tpf_news.park_id = tpf_parks.park_id GROUP BY name ORDER BY date DESC ' ;
$result2 = $pdo->query($sql2);
```

It was working fine until a theme park got more than one news story, the date being grouped is the older date not the newer so the theme park would remain at its original position, not jumping to the top of the list when it has a new story attached. How can I change the query so the grouping is done by most recent date?

If it's needed, below is the php foreach to display the data.

```
<?php foreach ($result2 as $row2): ?>
<h4>
<a class="bloglink" href="parknews.php?park_id=<?php echo $row2['park_id'];?>">
<?php echo $row2['name']; ?>
</a>
</h4>
<br>


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the datatype of `date` ? you'll want to order by `date` in descending order for the most recent to come first.  if you're date field is not of a date type, convert it: `ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date) DESC`

Comment: the datatype is date. It was all working until there were two dates for one theme park. I had to group the results because each park should only list once in the list

Comment: If datatype is "Date" Alter it to "Datetime". Also Use Auto increment or PK in group by clause.

Comment: Your usage of `group by` is illegal in SQL but MySQL doesn't reject it (as all other DBMS do) - it simply returns *random* results. See this for details: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting a date, so essentially it will use a "random" date. You could try selecting like this:

```
SELECT MAX(date) thedate, tpf_news.park_id, name
FROM tpf_news
INNER JOIN tpf_parks ON tpf_news.park_id = tpf_parks.park_id GROUP BY name ORDER BY thedate DESC
```

This selects the largest date within each group (name) and then orders by those dates.

Comment: The dates actually don't get displayed, it's just the park name. The date DESC is just to get right ordering

Comment: Yes, but you still need to specify that you want the latest date, because that's the one you want to compare with. You don't have to use it in your `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

I just worked it out:

```
$sql2 = 'SELECT tpf_news.park_id, name
FROM tpf_news
INNER JOIN tpf_parks ON tpf_news.park_id = tpf_parks.park_id GROUP BY name 

ORDER BY min(STR_TO_DATE(date, "%Y-%m-%d"))'
```

That seems to do the job.
Thanks

Comment: That'll work if your data is coincidentally in the correct order, in the order mysql looks through the colums, with latest entries having highest date. However, if that becomes inconsisten you just get a random date for each grouping.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tpf_news.park_id, name
FROM tpf_news
INNER JOIN tpf_parks ON tpf_news.park_id = tpf_parks.park_id 
GROUP BY name ORDER BY date DESC, **(AutoIncrement_Field)** DESC
```

Hope This Will Help..